# Run report of donors with email addresses

Tags: email

How do I run a report that lists anyone who is a donor and has an email address in my organization's database on civi?

Answer (score 1):

You can search in advanced search for 'has an email' by putting a percent(%) sign in the email search field & hitting enter - and include a 'From 0' in the Contribution section of the search.

The resulting search should give results for

> Email LIKE '%' ...AND... Contribution Amount - greater than "0"